# I want to rewrite all documents in a collection with firebase functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am developing an app in flutter. I would like to rewrite the　value of "life" field of all documents in the "users" collection of the Firestore to "10(int)" at `00:00` Tokyo time.
I managed to write the code anyway, but I am completely clueless about JavaScript　and Functions, so it doesn't work.　　I would like to know how to correct it.　This is my code.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

process.env.TZ = "Asia/Tokyo";

export const checkTimezone = functions.region('asia-northeast1').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  console.info(process.env.TZ)
});

exports.timer = functions.pubsub.schedule('00***').onRun((context) => {
    functions.logger.info("timer1 start", {structuredData: true});
    admin.firestore().collection("users").get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            doc.ref.update({
                life:10
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: You aren't returning the promise chain that is returned by the `CollectionReference#get()` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default timezone for Cloud Functions is `America/Los_Angeles`. You can set the timezone to `Asia/Tokyo` so the function will run at every midnight in Japan. Also, you must return a promise from the function to terminate it once the updates have been completed. Try refactoring to code as shown below:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.timer = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("0 0 * * *")
  .timeZone("Asia/Tokyo")
  .onRun((context) => {
    functions.logger.info("timer1 start", {structuredData: true});

    const usersRef = db.collection("users");

    return usersRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
      const promises = [];

      snapshot.forEach((doc, i) => {
        promises.push(doc.ref.update({ life: 10 }));
      });

      return Promise.all(promises);
    });
  });
```

Comment: "If you have many documents in users collection, it might be better to use Batched Writes as well." While I see this advice regularly, I recommend to only use batched writes if you want to perform an atomic write (which is their purpose). If there is any performance gained from using batched writes, it is more likely an implementation detail than by design as they are actually more likely to cause performance throughput bottlenecks in the storage layer. Parallel individual writes are simpler and recommended.

Comment: I agree. I just found updating documents individually to be slower in some cases on user side so batched writes are sometimes useful where response times should be lower.

Comment: I'd still recommend against using batches for this purpose. When I chatted with one of the backend engineers recently, they were quite surprised that folks are using batches for anything else than to ensure atomicity (their intended behavior).